# Lequel d' « à priori » ou « a priori » est le plus correct ?

Tags: orthographe, latin

Dans ma rédaction, « à priori » est corrigé en « a priori », alors que « à priori » est bien défini dans [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a%20priori), et pas « a priori ».

Dans la langue française, quelle forme est jugée correcte ? acceptable ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La locution *a priori* vient du latin (*a priori ratione* étant la forme complète). Ainsi, dire *a priori* est correct. La préposition latine qui est impliquée dans cette expression est *ab* et n'a rien à voir avec la préposition "à" du français.

Cependant, la forme **à priori** a été adoptée dans la réforme de 1990 car le français préfère réserver le "a" au verbe avoir.

Actuellement, aucune des deux graphies n'est fautive.

Comment: Merci. Je ne connaissais pas la réforme de 1990. Mais du coup "à priori" est officiellement correct mais les "purists" préfèrent "a priori".

Comment: Les personnes qui preferent respecter l'original latin sont "purists" maintenant?  :-)

Comment: On pourrait dire `puristes` en effet.