# In “J'espère que plus personne n'a d'a priori”, what does “a priori” mean?

Tags: expressions

I've heard that *a priori* normally is equivalent to *at first sight*, *in principle* but I don't see how it means that in this sentence:

> Il peut s'adresser j'espère que plus personne n'a d'a priori

Comment: There's probably a punctuation issue in your sentence.  "*J'espère que plus personne n'a d'a priori*" is OK as it is,  what comes before has no relation to it and it is not clear what  "*il peut s'adresser*" means. We don't usually use the verb "*s'adresser*" like that.

Comment: Shouldn't this usage of espérer require usage of the subjunctive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can tell from its position in the sentence:

> j'espère que plus personne n'a d'a priori.

that *a priori* is a **noun phrase**. It means a preconceived idea. It is synonym of *un préjugé*.

The phrase ***a (à) priori*** can also be:

- An adverbial phrase:

  > Il ne faut écarter à priori aucune hypothèse.
- An adjective phrase:

  > La modération à priori est une sécurité.

As an adverb or an adjective, it can be spelled *a priori* (old spelling, and then it is usually in italics as it is the Latin spelling) or « à priori » (1990 orthography reform). See [Lequel d' « à priori » ou « a priori » est le plus correct ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1961/358))

When it is a noun phrase:

> J'ai un a priori favorable pour la solution présentée.

It can be spelled *a priori* (no accent on the *a*) or as a single word: *apriori* (1990 orthography reform), and it is invariable.

Comment: So basically it means a preconception about something? Yes that makes sense in the context I found it. The meaning of the phrase seems to change quite a lot depending on how it is used in the sentence, unlike most other words and phrases.